# Time Series chart X-axis Time display

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am working on TimeSeries in jfreechart and in this chart time is represented as hh:mm:ss. But when I start time from 00:00:00, chart shows the start time 12:00:00 and it rotates after 24 hour, but I do not want rotation of time such I want to see 25:00:00 in place of 1:00:00.
Is there any solution for these problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

dont know if you still wanna know about that, but you can just use something like this:

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setAutoRange(true);
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
```

By using HH instead of hh you force SimpleDateFormat to write the date in 24h format.

Hope it helps!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create your own `TimeSeriesDataModel` to use with the chart.  Override the `getValueAt` method in your class to return a string formatted the way you want.

Comment: But I found only TimeSeriesTableModel not TimeSeriesDataModel and also found that the TimeSeriesTableModel maps the TimeSeries data into a JTable, that is not my requirement. I want to display Time 00:00:00 in place of 12:00:00 on the X-axis ticks of JFreeChart.